# UDP/IP と言わないのはなぜですか？

Tags: network, 専門用語

ネットワーク系の用語で TCP/IP という表記はよく目にしますが UDP/IP という表記はあまり見ません。
TCP も UDP も、どちらも IP ネットワーク上で実装されているプロトコルなのに奇妙に思います。
なぜ TCP だけ TCP/IP と表記しがちで UDP は UDP/IP と表記しないのでしょうか？

Answer (score 18, accepted):

TCP/IPというのはTCPとIPの組合せのみを指している言葉ではなく、TCP及びIPを含むプロトコル群の総称です。
1974年にはTCP/IPの最初の仕様である[RFC675](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc675)が制定されましたが、その当時はUDPというプロトコルは存在しませんでした。
UDPは1980年に[RFC786](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc768)が制定されTCP/IPに含まれることになりました。

歴史的な経緯で「TCP/IP」という表現になっていますがその中にはUDPも含まれているということです。
また、総称的な意味であれば「Internet Protocol Suite」という表現をする方が適切だとされることもあるので質問者さんと同じことを思っている人はそれなりに居るのではないでしょうか。

Comment: 用語「インターネットプロトコル一式」を慣用的に TCP/IP と呼び習わしているということであって TCP over IP １つのことではない、ということですね。そういうことなら、オイラ個人的には TCP/IP という用語は使わない方向でおｋです。インターネットプロトコル一式と呼ぶことにします。

Answer (score 5):

TCP/IPという用語はトランスポート層の１つTCPを指しているのではなく、[インターネット・プロトコル・スイート](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BC%E3%83%8D%E3%83%83%E3%83%88%E3%83%BB%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%83%88%E3%82%B3%E3%83%AB%E3%83%BB%E3%82%B9%E3%82%A4%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88)より

> インターネット・プロトコル・スイート（英: Internet protocol suite）とは、インターネットおよび大多数の商用ネットワークで稼動するプロトコルスタックを実装する通信プロトコルの一式である。インターネット・プロトコル・スイートは、インターネットの黎明期に定義され、現在でも標準的に用いられている2つのプロトコル、Transmission Control Protocol (TCP) とInternet Protocol (IP) にちなんで、**TCP/IP**プロトコル・スイートとも呼ばれる。

こちらの意味ではないでしょうか？
ですのでUDPを使用するDNSもTCP/IPに含められて扱われたりすると思います。